# I have two check boxes "Accept" and "Decline" and submit button. When i click on submit button it should check the which check box is ticked

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

```
{ field: "Accept", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.AcceptChk), "template": "<input type=\"checkbox\" # if (checkCommentsAccept(data.Comments)) { #disabled=\"disabled\" # } # />" },
{ field: "Decline", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.DeclineChk), "template": "<input type=\"checkbox\" # if (checkCommentsDecline(data.Comments)) { #disabled=\"disabled\" # } # />" },
{ field: "Item", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.Item) },
{ field: "PartID", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.PartID) },
{ field: "Description", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.Description), width: '300px' },
{ field: "SubPart", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.SubPart) },
{ field: "SubPartDescription", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.SubPartDescription) },
{ field: "BusinessPartner", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.BusinessPartner) },
{ field: "ReqDelTM", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.ReqDelTM) },
{ field: "EarDelTM", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.EarDelTM) },
{ field: "EarDelDate", title: "Ear Del Date", hidden: true },
{ field: "Comments", title: commonLib.readMessageByUserLanguage(COLUMNTITLENAME.Comments) }
```

When i click submit button it should check accept checkbox is checked or not if is checked then i have some logic. If decline check box is checked then i have some other logic.

Comment: Have a look at the question ... have you thought about editing it?

Comment: On click of submit button it should check accept checkbox is checked.

Comment: else if ((dataList[counter].Comments != "" && dataList[counter].Comments != null) && (dataList[counter].SubPart == "" || dataList[counter].SubPart == null)) {
                      var updateDate = {};
                        updateDate["lvidg_workorderproductstatuscode"] = window.opener.WOP_SYSTEMSTATUS.Pending;   in the place of if else condition i need a new condition else if (accept check box is checked) then do some update status

Comment: `else if (` you can't start a javascript code with `else if` ... strike 2

Comment: just give me a if condition . "If accept check box is checked"

Answer (score 0):

This really just comes down to how to stop an event from performing its native behavior.

If a submit button is pressed, the form's `submit` event is triggered. So, if your checkbox isn't checked at that time, you'll need to stop the event, which is done with [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). If the checkbox is checked, simply don't do anything and allow the submit to happen.

Here's an example:

```js
// Get reference to the checkbox
let chk = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");

// Set up event handler on the form
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event){

  // Check to see if the checkbox was not checked
  if(!chk.checked){
    event.preventDefault();  // Stop the submit event
    alert("You must agree before continuing.");
    return;
  }
  
  // If we get to this point in the code, the checkox was checked
  // and the form will submit.

});
```

```html
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkAgree" 
         id="chkAgree" value="agree">
  I agree to the terms of this site.
  <br>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is checkbox you might have implemented that only single checkbox is checked right ?, other wise there might be possibility that Accept & Declined both checkbox are checked ,

assuming that you have implemented single select checkbox logic

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if($("input[type='checkbox']:checked")[0].val() == 'Allow'){
    // things to done on allowed
  }else  if($("input[type='checkbox']:checked")[0].val() == 'Declined'){
    // things to done on declined
  }else{
    // rest things 
  }
});
```

you might need to change code a bit , but it will logically work as per your need.

Comment: I need to click submit button if accept check box is checked then  logic will trigger.

Comment: so you want to disable submit button and enable it only if accept checkbox is checked. is that correct ?

Comment: no not like that if I check accept checkbox and when I click on submit button some logic will trigger. I have that logic, but the problem is I want one if condition "if Accept checkbox is checked " then change status on click of submit. R